# How did this 1-rep user manage to create the tag "raspberry"?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

If you take a look at [the first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23303857/1) for the question [IndentationError: expected an indented block 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303857/indentationerror-expected-an-indented-block-10), you will notice that the user tagged their question with [raspberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raspberry) and [pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pi) rather than [raspberry-pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi). There are questions tagged with [pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pi) (computing pi, etc), but there are no questions tagged with [raspberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raspberry) (now that I have fixed the user's mistagging).

How did the user manage to create the tag [raspberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raspberry) in the first place? Don't you need 1500 rep to do that?

Comment: They probably didn't. Someone else probably created it and it got removed from the question, and the tag just didn't get killed off yet (and was thus still eligible for use).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As animuson notes, the tag was created by someone else: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23280084/revisions

Now that it has been removed from both questions, it'll die a quiet death until the next person with >= [1.5K rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) fat-fingers it.