# Can we stop the flow of burnination requests by limiting the amount of tags created

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

> A few days ago I wrote this text as an answer to this question:
>   [Do we need to rethink, clarify criteria for burnination?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366186/) Seeing as it didn't
>   get much attention there I thought it deserved its own stage, hence
>   this question.

---

Seeing the large number of burnination requests with punny titles, and only a few with the more [serious ones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) it is clear that we can't keep up with the rate they are coming at.

So whilst burnination is certainly a important part of keeping Stack Overflow tidy, it is only a curative tool. Why don't we take things to the root of the problem:

**The creation of tags.**

At this point in time creation of tags is easy and straightforward, as per the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

It is open to anyone with 1500 reputation points, and only requires those users to enter the tag to be created into the tag box. I think this creation system can be improved.

Currently:

> - on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.
> - meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, are not allowed.

If a tag is only used once in half a year is a very loose criteria if you ask me,  <del>if we could reduce this period to a month, or maybe 3 months,</del> I wonder how many tags get removed by the system (Moderator tools/report, anyone?).

*In retrospect this automatic removal of tags isn't that usefull, as it is again curative, albeit low effort*

Also you can read that Meta tags are not allowed, however no-one will stop you from [creating the `[gaming]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360795) tag.

**Improvements**

I think the best way would be a (thorough) redesign of the tag creation process which:

- Requires a tag to have complete info (summary etc.) when being created.
- Has a review system on tag creation where users can approve, edit, or reject a new tag. Here there would be an option to indicate that there already is a tag describing the subject, a tag is too localized, too broad etc.
- Allows a tag to be used when creation is pending. This will prevent tags from being requested twice at the same time.  <del>Don't allow it to be used as the sole tag on a question, and</del>  make the tag in creation distinct from accepted tags, either by using a different fill color on the tag, or a distinct symbol pre/super-seding the tag. If a tag is not accepted onto the network, remove all instances of that tag, or retag them with the review concensus on the alternative.

---

These are my two cents, I'd like to hear about yours!

---

I just found an old post on the same topic: [Make it harder to create tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288894). The numbers in the accepted answer are different now: ˜54K tags on SO, instead of 40k and 2600 posts on Meta regarding tags, compared to 885. Hence the then 2% is now close to 5%. Indicating that the balance is shifting. At this point in time there are also 596 pending burnination requests, out of a total of 887 posts tagged [burnination-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burnination-request) (excluding deleted posts).

Comment: For the first option how will you prevent users to enter gibberish? _"Tag info: asldhjgfokuasgdfjhasdfjhgasdfjhadjshgfjausdgfjasbdfljhasdgfljhagdsfl"_

Comment: @AndréKool Thank you for the valid point you raise André. Personally I'm not that into that sort of mechanisms. A review on that sort of entry would be pretty simple though: reject since the tag info is missing. However I bet that there could be some sort of check on the quality of an entry, just like SO checks for the amount of code in a post etc.

Comment: I'm no fan of review queues. How about limiting the amount of tags a user can create? Maybe at most 1 tag per day, and/or a limit of pending tags. The exact numbers would need to be fleshed out.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I think it would be helpfull to see some actual data about tag creation first. Your suggestion would work very well for 1 user creating 1000 tags but it would do nothing if its 1000 users each creating 1 tag.

Comment: @AndréKool Agreed. It would take a few SEDE queries to get such limits right.

Comment: @S.L.Barth a quick view on the user list learns that there are >95K users with 1500 reputation. There are 596 burnination request that are pending, so not accepted or declined. 276 are completed and 24 declined, so only a third of everything has been handled. The limit would then need to be very stringent, like once upon a SO-lifetime to make a difference.

Comment: Your search does not account for cases where the real request is for a tag to be renamed and includes duplicate requests. Not to mention that the tag is close to 5 years old which means that some of those 569 pending requests are pretty much dead and not going to happen. I think more data about the creation rate of good vs bad tags is needed.

Comment: Don't allow the tag to be used as the sole tag on a question? So if the question is about a new framework and no existing tags apply to the question the op should just put another random tag on it?

Comment: @JoeW, adding a random tag certainly isn't helpfull either. My reason for adding this was to prevent questions from having 0 tags if a tag doesn't get accepted. But hearing your remark, having a random tag might actually be more harmfull.

Comment: But how old are the tags that are being burninated? If they're all from years ago (when the tags seemed like a good idea) then restricting new tags wouldn't help much.

Comment: @OrangeDog If I look at the newest tags page I see someone decided it was worth creating [tag:android-native], which is a synonym for [tag:android-ndk]. This can be fixed rather quickly now, but if a few dozen questions pile up on the tag it will become more work to get rid of it. As of now it has no questions attached, but the tag merely being created by someone with 1.5k rep makes it open to anyone to use.

Comment: @Luuklag anecdotes are not statistical evidence

Comment: Well then, I looked at the most recently completed burnination's ( [customapi] , [checker-board], [data-change]). They where all done swiftly as it was clear they were tags we don't want to keep, and had limited questions. I can't see however when the tags were created, as there no longer is a tag description page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding [the workflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) here.

[burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)s are not "outstanding". A request, like any other suggestion, stays there until it gets community approval to be carried out.

If it never gets enough support and/or attention, it will just stay on the site, open, indefinitely (unless the author accepts an answer to it, signifying that they accept the (alternative) resolution that it provides). Anyone interested is supposed to find it with search, so there's no harm in it falling off the front page.

Comment: Ivan, thanks for your remarks. I refined my search a bit to accomodate for your remarks. Searching for [burninate-requests] that are not completed or declined, are without an accepted answer and have a score of 20 or more and excluding closed posts. This yields a backlog of 203 requests, of which one is currently featured. This is still far more then we can cope with.

Comment: @Luuklag that's certainly not "more than we can cope with". If e.g. featuring 3 at a time, we'll be done in 4 months. Why the mods are lazy with pushing them to stage 2 is another question for another discussion.

Comment: I'd like to point you to the following answer by Cody_Gray: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356820/#356821 "handling one per week is pretty much the fastest possible rate." If we were to do three at a time, which would seriously mess up the UI though, that would still take us 67,7 weeks.... Or 1 year and 3,5 months...